# How to refresh list item after sorting immediately

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a music list obtained from:

**MusicDatabase.kt**

```
override fun getContentProviderValue(): MutableList<Songs> {

    val songList =  mutableListOf<Songs>()
    val collection = sdk29AndUp {
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
    } ?:  MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

    //Get songs from provider
    context.contentResolver.query(
        collection,
        projection,
        selection,
        null,
        PreferenceHelper.storeAllSongsSortOrder //Sort order.
    ).use { cursor -> 
    ............
 }
}
```

Using SharedPreference, I am storing and obtaining sort order like this:

**PreferenceHelper.kt**

```
//store allSongs sort order
var storeAllSongsSortOrder: String?
    get() = preferences.getString(allSongSortOrder.first, allSongSortOrder.second)
    set(value) = preferences.edit {
        if (value != null) {
          it.putString(allSongSortOrder.first, value)
    }
}
```

I obtain the songList like this:

**SongsFragment.kt**

```
 mainViewModel.mediaItems.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ result->
 when(result.status) {
 Status.SUCCESS -> {
 result.data?.let { songs ->        
 allSongsAdapter.songs = songs
 ........
 }
```

In my songs fragment, when user clicks "Sort", a dropdown will appear with 2 options:

1. Sort by name
2. Sort by date

When user clicks sort by name, I do this:

**SongsFragment.kt**

```
PreferenceHelper.storeAllSongsSortOrder = Constants.SORT_TITLE
binding.rcvAllSongs.invalidate()
allSongsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

When user clicks sort by date, I do this:

```
 PreferenceHelper.storeAllSongsSortOrder = Constants.SORT_LAST_ADDED
 binding.rcvAllSongs.invalidate()
 allSongsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

**PROBLEM**: The list is not updating real time as I select, I have to close the app and open before my list gets the selected sort order.

I want - when I click e.g "Sort by date" - The list should update immediately and display songs based on date added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can propably do something like this:

```
class YourFragment : Fragment {
 
  private val allSongsAdapter = SongsAdapter()

  override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
  ): View {
    //init your views, bindins, view model and your recycler view adapter
    //...
    binding.recyclerView.adapter = allSongsAdapter
  }
  
  //...
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    mainViewModel.songList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { result ->
      when (result.status) {
        Status.SUCCESS -> {
          allSongsAdapter.updateList(result.data)
        }
      }
    })
    
    //or whatever you have on your UI to change your filter
    binding.sortFilter.setOnClickListener { filter ->
      mainViewModel.updateSortFilter(filter)
    }
    
    //....
    viewModel.initList()
  }
}
```

```
class YourViewModel() : ViewModel() {

  private var _unsortedSongList: List<String> = emptyList()
  
  private val _songList = MutableLiveData<Songs>()
  val songList: LiveData<Songs> = _songList

  private lateinit var musicDatabase: MusicDatabase

  init {
    musicDatabase = //get the dependency or inject it from constructor
    _unsortedSongList = musicDatabase.getContentProviderValue()
  }

  fun initList() {
    _songList.value = sortSongs(PreferencesHelper.storeAllSongsSortOrder)
  }

  fun updateSortFilter(sortFilter: String) {
    PreferencesHelper.storeAllSongsSortOrder = sortFilter
    _songList.value = sortSongs(sortFilter)
  }

  private fun sortSongs(sortFilter: String): List<Songs> {
    var sortedList: List<Songs> = emptyList()
    switch (sortFilter) {
      Constants.SORT_LAST_ADDED -> {
        sortedList = _unsortedSongList.sortedBy { it.createdMillis }
      }
      Constants.SORT_LAST_ADDED -> {
        sortedList = _unsortedSongList.sortedBy { it.name }
      }
    }
    return sortedList
  }


}
```

```
class SongsAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<SongItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {
  private val songsList = mutableListOf<Songs>()

  fun updateList(list: List<Songs>) {
    songsList.clear()
    songsList.addAll(list)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
  }

  //.... the rest of your adapter and viewholder
}
```

Comment: I am stuck at 'fun sortSongs'  //"sort the items based on your sort filter"..

What i'm I supposed to do there, please??

Comment: I'm I supposed to provide a sorting mechanism..? Cant the list be updated based on the sortOrder from contentResolver...which is saved in SharedPreference

Comment: That's a business logic decision. Usually if the query is simple, the is no pagination and results aren't thousand of rows the best thing is sorting them before sending them to the UI layer.
I would start with filtering them in this way, then if you see a performance problem you can change the viewmodel a bit and reload the list every time the filter is changed

Comment: I've added a sample on how you could filter in the ViewModel (i've not runned it, it is just to give you the idea)

Comment: Thanks. I've been able to implement it. but the list doesn't start from the top after sorting. It stays at the current item, I have to scroll up to the start of the list

Comment: If you want to move to the start after sorting, you can do it using the RecyclerView manager, something like this: `mLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);` after `allSongsAdapter.updateList(result.data)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235026/discussion-between-ibccx-and-matpag).

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning the updated list to allSongsAdapter after user presses a button.

```
 PreferenceHelper.storeAllSongsSortOrder = Constants.SORT_LAST_ADDED | Constants.SORT_TITLE
 binding.rcvAllSongs.invalidate()
 allSongsAdapter.songs = songs         // You have to update the Adapter data set with sorted list
 allSongsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

So either you make sure that `mainViewModel.mediaItems.observe` is invoked when user selects sort, which is only possible if MusicTable is updated or you save the list received in `mainViewModel.mediaItems.observe` in a variable and then sort and reassign it when user wants to sort the list

Comment: Can you show me how to go about option 2.

I have saved the list of songs obtained from mainViewModel in a variable but I dont understand the "then sort it and reassign it" part.

Comment: Just use the same logic as you use in `mainViewModel.mediaItems` but instead of using the list returned from db use the one you saved

Comment: Thanks.. along with @MatPags answer, I have been able to implement it